# Wifi is disabled by hardware switch HP pavilion

Tags: wireless

My Wifi works fine on Windows 10, but when I switch to Ubuntu 16.04 (my system has dual boot), it says 'Wifi is disabled by hardware switch'. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Output of

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -A3 '^System Information'


System Information
Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
Product Name: HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC
Version: 098C110000404100000610180
```

Output of

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink WLAN Ralink RT3290LE Roma 802.11bgn 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 combo HMC
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

It maybe caused due to three reasons.
1.bios disabled the wifi
  all you have to do is check bios and make sure u turn the wireless on or
  simply reset the bios

2.the wifi switch (usually a function key) is off
  find that key and turn on the wifi

3.it is due to ubuntu (most likely):
  try these in order
  enter in a terminal:

```
    rfkill unblock all
```

check if it worked by typing in

```
    rfkill list
```

if it is still hardblocked, then, try my last advice.
  first type in the terminal

```
    lsmod | grep -w wmi
```

Now in the output, remember the last word you see after the numbers.
  Type in the terminal now while replacing ideapad-laptop with what you 
  saw in the previous output(for my lenovo, ideapad-laptop was the name).

```
    sudo modprobe ideapad-laptop
```

That probably should work( it did for me)

references: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2198155

This is my first answer in ubuntu forms, so forgive me if the answer is not upto the mark.

Comment: I tried resetting the BIOS through 'Load Setup Defaults' option. Additionally, I tried to reset the hardware settings of my laptop by removing the battery and holding the power button for 15-20 sec. All this, including the commands mentioned, did not solve my problem.